# How to upgrade forms from google captcha v2 to captcha v3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, recaptcha, captcha

I have two form on one page and I'm currently using google captcha v2 but I want to upgrade the form to captcha v3, is there an easey way to do this.

From the documentation I read that using this code will work, but it only works for one form
and it ignores my first click that check all the required field on my forms.

```
<script>
      function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
              // Add your logic to submit to your backend server here.
          });
        });
      }
  </script>

<form role='form' method='POST' id='myForm' enctype='multipart/form-data' class='hiddenContent myForm2'>
    <center><div id='myCaptchaDiv1'></div></center> 
    <div class='form-row'> 
        <div class='col-12' id='btn-subtmit'>  
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn-controls'>Submit <i class='fas fa-check'></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>


<form role='form' method='POST' id='myForm' enctype='multipart/form-data' class='hiddenContent myForm2'>
    <center><div id='myCaptchaDiv2'></div></center> 
    <div class='form-row'> 
        <div class='col-12' id='btn-subtmit'>  
          <button class='btn btn-primary btn-controls'>Submit <i class='fas fa-check'></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var CaptchaCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('myCaptchaDiv1', {'sitekey' : 'myoid'});
        grecaptcha.render('myCaptchaDiv2', {'sitekey' : 'myoid'});
    };
</script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added an event listener to both forms? The forms have to have unique IDs (you posted them both as 'myForm'), and make sure you register the `onClick` callback like so:

```js
const form1 = document.getElementById('myForm1');
const form2 = document.getElementById('myForm2');
form1.addEventListener('submit', onClick);
form2.addEventListener('submit', onClick);
```

Any form validation that you might to do (checking the required fields), you can do *before* `grecaptcha.ready(...)`. An example:

```js
<script>
      function onClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // DO FIELD CHECKS. If invalid, then return;
        ...
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
              // Add your logic to submit to your backend server here.
          });
        });
      }
</script>
```